# Run websocket from localhost in php(ci4)

Tags: php

I want to run websocket from my localhost, When i run this command (php index.php server index) then show the error, please have you any answer please help me.

**ERRROR:Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:80": An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

[image: https://prnt.sc/gqoMyPviUG0T]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please can you [edit] your question to include the relevant code and full error message as text in the question itself, so we don't have to click some unknown link just to see what the question is; and so that others can see the question in future when that site might not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put the word **text** in bold - images are hard to read, impossible to search for, impossible to copy and paste into answers, and just generally less useful than the actual text itself.